# com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException error while registration using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Good day , I am using volley for registration and i am getting this error

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

here is my code link :- https://paste.ubuntu.com/25059096/

Comment: comment  error.toString();
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());

Comment: @Pravin still getting error

Comment: you are getting an error in onErrorResponse so check for the null condition in onErrorResponse as well

Comment: Use TextUtils.isEmpty(response) to check for null and length both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: if(response != null) is enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are passing anyone of the parameter is null then also your response will be null. First check your parameters what you are passing.